# How to remove "Annual visitors survey" malware from a wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cpanel, malware

I have a WordPress website. when I enter the address in any Explorer or click on the Google search result link, it opens an unrelated page like "Annual visitors survey".
I installed the Wordfance plugin and scanned the website then I removed any code that Wordfance was alarmed about it. but after several hours the malware comes back again and redirects me to unrelated pages.

the URLs that malware redirects me to them are:
"https://107.newshurttab.live/urfregsp/?utm_campaign=..."
&
"https://paybooroom.live/?utm_campaign=INccHxHRWrew3TQsLBbfNnbGFYUZobMqxXT9Zrw5FhI1&t=main9expsess"
&...

How can I resolve this problem? I even changed all passwords.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server